# E2E Test application flow on multiple devices

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

Our applications flow start on desktop. At later phase there are some scenarios where the processes require an approval on a touch device. The user waits at a page on desktop. If the user opens the same page (same angular application) on a touch device then another page opens where he/she needs to accept or reject the flow. The user blocked on desktop during the tablet phase, but after it was accepted (or rejected) the flow moves to the next (or previous) page.

We would like to create some e2e test for those scenarios. I thought we could open a chrome browser instance (normal, desktop mode), go to tablet phase, then open chrome instanse (touch device compatibility) and after continue on desktop. Are there any way to achieve something like this? 
Currently we use angular 8 with protactor but any framework is fine.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is probably better suited to [Software Quality Assurance & Testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use multiCapabilities for parallel execution. You can visualize this using the below code, I use this code to open Safari on IPad and chrome on my windows VM in parallel. Keep in mind that, this runs the same spec simultaneously:

```
    multiCapabilities: [
    {
      /** IPad support.**
       * To install Appium, please use command: webdriver-manager update --ios
       * refer more from here: https://www.protractortest.org/#/mobile-setup
       */
      browserName: 'safari',
      platformName: 'iOS',
      platformVersion: '7.1',
      deviceName: 'IPad Simulator',
    },
    {
      browserName: "chrome",
      shardTestFiles: true,
      maxInstances: 2,
      chromeOptions: {
        useAutomationExtension: false,
        args: ["–disable-gpu"]    //"--headless", "--incognito", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=800,600"
      }
    }
   ]
```